# PySpark using both aggregate and group by

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, tpc

Can someone help me with pyspark using both aggregate and groupby functions? I have made my data frames, and applied filters and selects to get the data I want. However, I am now stuck trying to aggregate things correctly.

Currently, my code outputs the content below:

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+----------+---------+
|l_orderkey|o_orderdate|o_shippriority|l_extendedprice|l_discount|      rev|
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+----------+---------+
|     53634| 1995-02-22|             0|       20517.44|      0.08|18876.045|
|    265539| 1995-01-25|             0|       70423.08|      0.01| 69718.85|
|    331590| 1994-12-10|             0|       46692.75|      0.03| 45291.97|
|    331590| 1994-12-10|             0|        37235.1|       0.1| 33511.59|
|    420545| 1995-03-05|             0|        75542.1|      0.04|72520.414|
|    420545| 1995-03-05|             0|         1062.0|      0.07|987.66003|
|    420545| 1995-03-05|             0|        9729.45|       0.1| 8756.505|
|    420545| 1995-03-05|             0|        15655.6|      0.04|15029.375|
|    420545| 1995-03-05|             0|         3121.3|      0.03|3027.6611|
|    420545| 1995-03-05|             0|        71723.0|      0.03| 69571.31|
|    488928| 1995-02-15|             0|        1692.77|      0.01|1675.8423|
|    488928| 1995-02-15|             0|       22017.84|      0.01|21797.662|
|    488928| 1995-02-15|             0|       57100.42|      0.04|54816.402|
|    488928| 1995-02-15|             0|        3807.76|      0.05| 3617.372|
|    488928| 1995-02-15|             0|       73332.52|      0.01|72599.195|
|    510754| 1994-12-21|             0|       41171.78|      0.09| 37466.32|
|    512422| 1994-12-26|             0|       87251.56|      0.07| 81143.95|
|    677761| 1994-12-26|             0|       60123.34|       0.0| 60123.34|
|    956646| 1995-03-07|             0|       61853.68|      0.05|58760.996|
|   1218886| 1995-02-13|             0|        24844.0|      0.01| 24595.56|
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+----------+---------+
```

I wish to apply a group by: l_orderkey and aggregate the Rev as a sum.

Here is my most recent attempt with 't' being the dataframe and F being functions from pyspark.sql `"from pyspark.sql import functions as F"`

```
(t .groupby(t.l_orderkey,t.o_orderdate, t.o_shippriority) 
 .agg(F.collect_set(sum(t.rev)), F.collect_set(t.l_orderkey)) .show())
```

Can someone help me know if I'm on the right track? I keep getting "Column is not iterable"

Comment: did the proposed answer work for you?

Comment: Thank you ggordon, I did get the answer to work once you explained that sum was trying to use the native python sum. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
total_rev = t.groupby(t.l_orderkey).agg(F.sum(t.rev).alias('total_rev'))

# print /show the top results
total_rev.show()
```

would give you a new df with columns `l_orderkey, total_rev` where `total_rev` would store the aggregated sum of `rev`

You use [`collect_set`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set.html) when attempting to remove duplicates.

You are also getting  `Column is not iterable` because you are using the built in python function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and not the `spark` function [`F.sum`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sum.html)